# Can't get date from bootstrap date picker

Tags: java, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, date, servlets

We're doing a project and there's a date picker in Bootstrap, the problem is, I can't seem to get it in my servlet. Here's the code for the date picker:

```
<div class="bfh-datepicker" data-max="today" data-close="false" data-date="today" data-format="y-m-d">
      <input id="birthdate" type="text" data-name="birthdate" name='birthdate' style='background-color:white;'>
</div>
```

And here's my code for relaying the information to the database:

```
stmt3.setString(5, request.getParameter("birthdate"));
```

I made the birthdate column in the database varchar for now just to test if the servlet is getting the information, but I guess it doesn't. Also, if I happen to get the information from the date picker:

1. Does it return a string?
2. If it returns a string, how am I supposed to convert it to date then put it in my database?

NOTE: I'm using Java and MySQL

Comment: Do you have Form tag outside input?

Comment: Yes of course. Other input tags are also inside one form tag.

Answer (score 0):

Include `JS` files.Try this

```
     <input class="datepicker_multi_start" name="datepicker[]"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()

{ 

$("#append").click( function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});

</script>
```